# How to handle file names with spaces in zenity commands

Tags: bash, scripts, filename, zenity

I am developing a GUI search program. I need help to handle filenames with spaces. I just can't figure it out.
Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

USERNAME=$(whoami)

INPUT=$(zenity --entry)

updatedb --require-visibility 0 -o ~/.locate.db

FILEMATCHES=$(locate --database ~/.locate.db -i -b -c "$INPUT")
echo "$FILEMATCHES matches found"

if [ $FILEMATCHES == 0 ]; then
    echo "no file matches found"
    exit 1
fi

FOUNDFILES=($(locate --database ~/.locate.db -i -b "$INPUT"))

x=0

while [ $x -lt $FILEMATCHES ]
do
    if [ $x == 0 ]
        then
        echo -n "--list --title FILE-SELECTOR --column serialno. --column file --radiolist TRUE "${FOUNDFILES[$x]}" --width 1000 --height 600" >> /home/$USERNAME/tempzen.txt
        x=$((x+1))
    else
        echo " FALSE ${FOUNDFILES[$x]}" >> /home/$USERNAME/tempzen.txt
        x=$((x+1))
    fi
done

ZEN=$(cat /home/$USERNAME/tempzen.txt)
echo $ZEN

SELECTEDFILE=$(zenity $ZEN)
if [ $? -eq 0 ] 
then
    zenity --progress --pulsate --timeout 2
fi
echo "You have selected $SELECTEDFILE"

EXTENSION=$(file --mime-type $SELECTEDFILE)
echo $EXTENSION
if [ "$SELECTEDFILE" == "" ]
    then
        echo "You didn't select any file to open..."
        rm /home/$USERNAME/tempzen.txt
        exit 1
fi

if [ "$SELECTEDFILE" != "" ] && [ "$EXTENSION" == "$SELECTEDFILE: inode/x-empty" ] || [ "$EXTENSION" == "$SELECTEDFILE: text/plain" ] || [ "$EXTENSION" == "$SELECTEDFILE: application/xml" ]
    then
        gedit $SELECTEDFILE
elif [ "$SELECTEDFILE" != "" ] && [ "$EXTENSION" == "$SELECTEDFILE: image/jpg" ] || [ "$EXTENSION" == "$SELECTEDFILE: image/jpeg" ] || [ "$EXTENSION" == "$SELECTEDFILE: image/gif" ] || [ "$EXTENSION" == "$SELECTEDFILE: image/png" ] || [ "$EXTENSION" == "$SELECTEDFILE: image/bmp" ]
    then
        xdg-open $SELECTEDFILE
elif [ "$SELECTEDFILE" != "" ] && [ "$EXTENSION" == "$SELECTEDFILE: text/html" ]
    then
        firefox $SELECTEDFILE
elif [ "$SELECTEDFILE" != "" ] && [ "$EXTENSION" == "$SELECTEDFILE: application/pdf" ]
    then
        gnome-open $SELECTEDFILE
fi

rm /home/$USERNAME/tempzen.txt
```

it works perfectly for files with no saces, but for example, i have a file  named very very latest (with all those spaces). So, when I input that input file name is stored as

```
zenity --list --title FILE-SELECTOR --column serialno. --column file --radiolist TRUE /home/jeevan/very
```

So only the filename up to `very` is stored, so the next file selection output window is also a mess:

[image: file selector with name broken at space]

I want the output to be

```
 zenity --list --title FILE-SELECTOR --column serialno. --column file --radiolist TRUE /home/jeevan/very very latest
```

And in the GUI it should be `/home/jeevan/very very latest`.

Comment: a) Use `find` instead of `locate`, or b), set `IFS=$"\n"`, since `locate` prints filenames separated by newlines.

Comment: Or put quotes around the filename (note that if you use double-quotes, you'll need to escape them).

Comment: @muru but when i store them in array, lets assume, there are two files, one is very very latest and the other is very.conf .  then if i use IFS new line it will consider both the files as same file name right? also if i use space in IFS it will take only upto very .. how to solve this problme?

Comment: hi saiarcot895 i tried it but then the output in the gui is like "home/jeevan/very" :(

Comment: I tested double quotes and it works fine with spaces, run this `file='/home/jeevan/very very latest';firefox "$file" ;`

Comment: @bistoco hey bro you might have checked separately, try my script and help me its not happening with my script

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems.  The `IFS` for the output of `locate`, and the `IFS` for `zenity`.

`IFS` is a shell variable containing a string of characters, any of which will break a string into words.  The usual value is '`space` `tab` `newline`'

Both are fixed by setting `IFS` to a newline immediately before running `locate`.

```
export IFS='
'
FOUNDFILES=($(locate --database ~/.locate.db -i -b "$INPUT"))
```

The second problem is fixed by `export`ing this value of `IFS` into the environment, so that it also affects `zenity`.  This means you also need to modify the creation of `tempzen.txt` to use newlines as word separators.

```
if [ $x == 0 ]
    then
    echo -e "--list\n--title\nFILE-SELECTOR\n--column\nserialno.\n--column\nfile\n--radiolist\nTRUE\n${FOUNDFILES[$x]}\n--width\n1000\n--height\n600" >> /home/$USERNAME/tempzen.txt
    x=$((x+1))
else
    echo -e "FALSE\n${FOUNDFILES[$x]}" >> /home/$USERNAME/tempzen.txt
    x=$((x+1))
fi
```